# Command Line 'free' get only the result from 'total'

Tags: unix, memory, command, line, free

I am using the command free and I get this:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       2061956    1675768     386188      30384     192060     543900
-/+ tampons/cache:     939808    1122148
Partition d'échange:    1046524       4292    1042232
```

But I really just want the result of total, here it's "201956" 
Do you if I can join with a grep or printf in my command line ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`free` tool gathers information by parsing `/proc/meminfo`.

---

The way to get the `MemTotal` value directly:

**`head`** + **`awk`** approach:

```
head -n1 /proc/meminfo | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you very much !